# Loading data from source table into multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a source table called `table1`, which populates every night with new data. I have to upload the data in 4 relational tables `tblCus, tblstore, tblEmp, tblExp`. Should I use a stored procedure or trigger to accomplish that?
Thanks

Comment: SSIS would be a good tool for this

Comment: You can create a scheduled job for this.

Comment: create a job and add your scritpn inside

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268(v=sql.105).aspx, no triggers or SPs.

Comment: Thanks. well consider all of that

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, there is always more than one way to skin a cat. From your question, I am making the assumption that you are denormalizing 4 tables from an OLTP-style database, into a single dimension in a data warehouse style application.

If the databases are on separate instances, or if only simple transformations are required, you could use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services).

If this is correct, and the databases reside on the same instance, then you could use a stored procedure.

If the transformation is part of a larger load, then you could combine the two methods, and use SSIS to orchestrate the transformations, but simply call-off stored procedures in the control flow.

The general rule I use, to decide if I should use a data flow, or a stored procedure, for a specific transformation is: Data Flow is my preference, but if I will require any asynchronous transformations within the data flow, I revert to a stored procedure. This general rule USUALLY gives the best performance profile.

I would avoid triggers, especially if there are a large number of DML operations against the 4 tables, as the trigger will fire for each modification and potentially cause performance degradation.

Comment: Thanks, Pete That was very helpful.

Comment: @Ashraf If it helped you, please don't forget to upvote and/or accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple load, you can use a `DataFlow Task` to select from `table1.`

> Assuming table1 is your source table for your 4 tables.

Then you can use a `Conditional split task` which acts like a where clause, where you can set your definitions for `tblCus, tblstore, tblEmp, tblExp` and then add 4 destinations for these.

**Look at my example:**
[image: Entire package]

**Conditional split:**
[image: Conditional split]

Comment: If you dont know how to filter it, you can also just write a stored procedure for each table and then create 4 Execute SQL Tasks in ssis which executes your stored procedures. There are many ways to do it :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together